# Netbeans Maven:Java Application when run several times creates multiple instances (once for each time run), resulting in a port confilct

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jetty

I generally use JEE and Glassfish to create web applications, however I've created a web application using Jetty which does not require a container. However each time I run the application I have to manually stop the currently running instance. This doesn't take long but it is a bit of a pain. I would like a smoother development cycle, I'm sure it can be automated at the command line and will do so, but I think it should be a pretty common issue.

I'm creating my project using NB 8.2. 
File -> New Project -> Under Categories selecting "Maven", Under Projects "Java Application"

Each time the project is run, a new running instance is deployed, such that after 5 runs there are 5 running programs (well that would normally be the case for this type of application but because of a port conflict I must stop the previous instance).

Any of the following would be a viable solution:

1. Ideally, if their is a running instance of the program it is compiled and relaunched on save, don't know if this is possible outside of a container like Glassfish.
2. The application kills any previous deployment and compiles and runs a new instance when "Run Project" button is pressed (F6).
3. Anything else that meets this intention.

For pom based solutions here is what I'm working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kenmcwilliams</groupId>
    <artifactId>MpawServices</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON parsing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fastjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>boon</artifactId>
            <version>0.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- needed for DB access -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- needed for Dagger2 DI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- to prevent: SLF4J: Failed to load class “org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder” -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.kenmcwilliams.mpawservices.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a feature in NetBeans at the moment, but you should be able to file a feature request at the [NetBeans Jira Issue Tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS). In fact, it would be a nice feature, I also searched for something similar in the past.

Comment: From recent reading there might be a way to specifically shutdown Jetty, by specifying a shutdown port/service in the POM. Which would solve the problem for this project still it would be nice if there was a general solution to only let one instance run... I'll search to see if a plugin exists that might do this. It seems straight forward, NB shows if applications are executing and lets you stop them, so when run is pressed, if there is an executing application by the same name then stop it first before clean/build or build.

Comment: Created an issue for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-42?filter=allopenissues&orderby=priority+ASC%2C+updated+DESC

Comment: Also poured over the plugins without success.

Comment: if you could vote for that issue it might help (vote on issues.apache.org I mean)